# Does IBM Watson Document Conversion ignores header?

Tags: ibm-watson, document-conversion

We are trying to use the IBM Watson [Document Conversion](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/document-conversion.html) service on Word documents and have noticed that text that is in the header (and is displayed when the doc file is viewed) is not returned by the document conversion service.  Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 1):

The Watson Document Conversion service **filters out** headers and footers on purpose so that the converted output is a clean, readable text.

Typically, headers and footers contain repeating phrases or words (e.g. chapter title) or numbers (e.g. page number), which is usually not desirable to have in the output HTML or plain text.